# ClassLoader name for java.lang.String coming as null

Tags: java, classloader

```
class Test {

}

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Test t = new Test();
        String s = new String("abc");
        Integer i = new Integer(1000);
        System.out.println(Class.forName("Test").getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(NewClass.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(java.lang.String.class.getClassLoader());
        System.out.println(java.lang.Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@546b97fd
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@546b97fd
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@546b97fd
null
null
```

In the above code, why is the class loader for String and Integer null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the JavaDoc of [getClassLoader()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader%28%29)

> Returns the class loader for the class. Some implementations may use
>   null to represent the bootstrap class loader. **This method will return
>   null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader.**

Bootstrap class loader is responsible for loading class which is defined in Java API. `String` and `Integer` class are getting loaded by Bootstrap class loader.

Comment: Should have looked at the documentation more closely :). thanks